# Solving a functional system of polynomial equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

I found this problem somewhere, and have been trying to solve it for some time now, but I have been stuck. Please can you share any hints that would help me to solve this problem.

The problem statement:

> Two polynomials $P$ and $Q$ satisfy $P(-2x + Q(x)) = Q(P(x) - 2x)$. If $Q(x) = x^2 - 4$ and $P(x) = ax + b$, find $2a + b$.

Comment: Just substitute and try to figure it out.

Comment: @Ekene Ezeunala, would you like to accept any of these answers below. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Substituting the value of $P(x)$ and $Q(x) $ and simplifying, we get, 
$$x^2(a^2-5a+4) +x(2a+2ab-4b) +b^2-b+4a-4=0$$
Since, this expression is true $\forall \;x$, it becomes an identity. So, the coefficient of $x^2, \;x$ and the constant term are individually equal to zero. 
$$\therefore (a, b) =(1, 1) $$

Answer (score 0):

$$Q(P(x)-2x)=((a-2)x+b)^2-4=(a²-4a+4)x^2 +(2ab-4b)x+b²$$

$$P(Q(x)-2x)=a(x²-2x-4) + b$$

Lets compare the coefficients of $x$

$$x^2 : a = a^2-4a+4$$
$$a=1, 4$$

$$x: -2a=2ab-4b$$
If $a =1$, $b = 1$
if $a=4, b =-2$

By plugging values of $a,b$ you can check if any of the solutions dont satisfy then reject them.